# Unable to connect or manage networks in Lubuntu 12.04 [VMWarePlayer]

Tags: networking, lubuntu, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a VPN inside VMWarePlayer running Lubuntu 12.04 but I'm not able to do it.

This is my NM's screen

**Edit:** Can't post screenshot

I can't change anything or connect to any interfaces via graphical interface. Is it normal? Apart from command line , how can I change network settings via GUI?
There are no VPN connections or other options, it shows just the details of the packets exchanged.

Comment: I've no control over the router...I'm at office! By the way, why can't I connect to network with the GUI? Something like old Windows right-clicking on network icon? Is it a bug? I can only see network properties...i.e. I've configured VPN but now how can I use it??? There is no "VPN connections"  like Ubuntu's...

Answer (score 0):

you need to port forward from your machine to current VM.
And also from your router(if any) to your machine.
I use virtual box which gives option to port forward

Comment: I've no control over the router...I'm at office!

Comment: But don't you have to connect inside Lubuntu to the VPN? Isn't there a connection icon anywhere...???

Comment: you know about upnp protocol?